# Populate database table with import script - django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm not seeing any 'straightforward' way to do what I want.

I have a fresh django app and I've created the initial migration of my database. It has one table. All seems good and I created a python script to import the data. I immediately get the below error after running it:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either
>   define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

**Model**

```
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    playerID = models.TextField()
    birthYear = models.IntegerField()
    birthMonth = models.IntegerField()
    birthDay = models.IntegerField()
    birthCountry = models.TextField()
    birthState = models.TextField()
    birthCity = models.TextField()
    deathYear = models.IntegerField()
    deathMonth = models.IntegerField()
    deathDay = models.IntegerField()
    deathCountry = models.TextField()
    deathState = models.TextField()
    deathCity = models.TextField()
    nameFirst = models.TextField()
    nameLast = models.TextField()
    nameGiven = models.TextField()
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    bats = models.TextField()
    throws = models.TextField()
    debut = models.DateField()
    finalGame = models.DateField()
    retroID = models.TextField()
    bbrefID = models.TextField()
```

**Import Script**

```
import pandas as pd
from api.models import Person

people_csv = pd.read_csv('data/People.csv')

people_objects = []
for p in people_csv.iterrows():
    person = Person()
    person.playerID = p.playerID
    person.birthYear = p.birthYear
    person.birthMonth = p.birthMonth
    person.birthDay = p.birthDay
    person.birthCountry = p.birthCountry
    person.birthState = p.birthState
    person.birthCity = p.birthCity
    person.deathYear = p.deathYear
    person.deathMonth = p.deathMonth
    person.deathDay = p.deathDay
    person.deathCountry = p.deathCountry
    person.deathState = p.deathState
    person.deathCity = p.deathCity
    person.nameFirst = p.nameFirst
    person.nameLast = p.nameLast
    person.nameGiven = p.nameGiven
    person.weight = p.weight
    person.height = p.height
    person.bats = p.bats
    person.throws = p.throws
    person.debut = p.debut
    person.finalGame = p.finalGame
    person.retroID = p.retroID
    person.bbrefID = p.bbrefID
    people_objects.append(p)

Person.objects.bulk_create(people_objects)
```

My assumption is that I need to add my import script somewhere in the setting.py or some other module. I'm just not 100% clear on the **where** and **what** I need to add.

**Folder Structure**

[image]

Comment: fixtures https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/initial-data/

Comment: Ah that error is nothing to do with your code. What's your folder structure look like, and your manage.py and settings.py files.

Comment: @Trent: So basically, convert my csv to json (or one of the supported formats) then just call `manage.py loaddata <fixturename>` and magic will happen?

Comment: @Trent: I added a screenshot of the folder structure :)

Comment: Why don't you make a view and upload data(csv file) from there?

Comment: It's just a onetime import. I'm reading through the options on how to enable in admin. I just really don't want to create the UI for it. It's starting to become a little more interesting though. Also exploring DataGrip > Import CSV...

Comment: Haven't used DataGrip, you can also try with custom management command.

Comment: @mwilson - yep, loaddata is magic for one off imports.